# How can I serve SVGs into a Flask Website

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

[image]

I am trying to display svg images on a website built with flask but unfortunately only the above icons show up. I have found similar questions on here but no answer that seems to fit my problem. My html code is the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% for name, name2 in zipp %}
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'data:image/svg+xml' + name) }}" ></img>
        <p>{{ name2 }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

While my flask app looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
b = os.getcwd()
listo2 = []
@app.route("/")
def home():
    for file in os.listdir(b):
        if file.endswith(".svg"):
            listo2.append(file)
    zipp = zip(listo2, listo2)
    return render_template("templates.html", zipp = zipp)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50853313/813946

Comment: @ArpadHorvath with a little modification this does indeed work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @1337_NOOB And you need the parantheses at the end of the read method, right. I'll correct it there, just I had no time to try.